# If $_SESSION['uname'] not equal to "teacher", go back to main page

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a page but I want to set it like only a member with "teacher" username can access to that page. There is a code like this I found:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
    
    header('location:(main page url)');
    exit;
    }
 ?>
```

This code works for non-logged in users. But I also want it to work for non-teacher username users.

I'm kinda new to PHP, I know It's really easy to solve, but I really need an answer.

How to do it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: if(!isset($_SESSION['uname'])) ... You are checking whether uname is set in session. You should also check if uname == teacher

Comment: I wrote this but still not working: if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']) && $_SESSION['uname'] != 'teacher')

Comment: It should be OR ( || ) not and ( && ) . your above code said  if session not set and uname not equal teacher. once session uname set then this condition goes false. thats thats reason for not working

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Now I totally understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.
option 1

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']) || $_SESSION['uname'] != 'teacher' ){

header('location:(main page url)');
die;
}
```

?>

option 2
You can pass user group through session eg:-

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['ugroup']) || !isset($_SESSION['uname']) ){
  if($_SESSION['ugroup'] != 'teacher' &&  $_SESSION['uname'] != valid User){
     header('location:(main page url)');
     die;
  }
}
```

?>

Comment: Ah! I used && instead of ||. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
function protect_teachers_area()
{
     if (is_logged_in() && $_SESSION['uname'] != 'teacher') {
        header('Location: /students_page.php');
        exit();
     }
}

function protect_page()
{
   if (!is_logged_in()) {
        header('Location: /index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
function is_logged_in()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['uname']);
}
```

Use these functions where ever required

```
protect_page();
protect_teachers_area();
```